# Printing special characters with umlauts in Scala

Tags: scala, character-encoding

i am having trouble printing special characters with umlauts.

I have a Scala program with `print("äö")` and it's printing `??`.

I have my VSCode set to UTF-8, I have specified scala to use UTF-8 with -encoding utf-8 when running. I am running on Windows and have set chcp 65001 as well.

Comment: Must be a windows specific-problem. This works fine in Firefox on Mac: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QlbrLz44TkeHKXpytrfSRQ (and the same stuff works on Mac command line etc).

Comment: How do you run the program? IDE? Console? .. Look's like an issue with the program that you use to display the output.

Comment: Thank you, still don't know how to solve tho. Tried setting windows to utf-8 with chcp 65001 but to no prevail...

Comment: I've tried running it in VSCode and Powershell, both give same response.

Comment: Where do you get your printed string from? Do yo actually type the umlauts with a keyboard or did you copy/paste them from somewhere? What happens if you convert them to Int (like [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/N1yHSkkSRme3tQ9PVSUTMg)) - do you get the same integer values as in scastie (228, 246, 252, 196, 214, 220 for ä, ö, ü, Ä, Ö, Ü)?

Comment: I've tried typing them out and copy pasting. I get the same values as scastie. Additional information: the length of "äöüÄÖÜ" is 6. I am saying this because the length of the characters sometimes change with different encodings.

Comment: Ok. Then I'm sorry, but I ran out of ideas (but I'm not a windows guy, so there's still hope that others can help ;)).

Comment: Maybe try to write to a file to see what happens. I mean redirect output of the program to a file. Or directly write to file from your code.

Comment: Tried writing to a file using PrintWriter and FileWriter but both wrote `������` instead of `äöüÄÖÜ`